# R 3.1 install automap package on mac

Tags: r, package, automap

Since updating R to 3.1 having trouble installing automap package on a mac.

```
    > install.packages("automap")

       package ‘automap’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

    Warning in install.packages :
     package ‘automap’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

Cannot workout how to install from source - can anyone help please ?

Update: Ok I got this to install eventually by downloading the source and using R CMD INSTALL at the command line. But I had to manually install gstat and spacetime this way first. When in Rstudio and using the package install tool via the menu - none of these packages come up in the list of packages on CRAN - why is this happening ? I did not have to do all this in R 2.15 that I can recall. Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: Are you using `Mavericks` or `Snow Leopard`?

Comment: Mavericks 10.9.3. RStudio 0.98.501. Sorry I should have included that